# Displaying record between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display a database record between two date ranges using PHP-mysql.
I am working on a project in which employees payment record is saved in a table. I want to see what amount has been paid between two dates selected through date-picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT amount FROM mytable WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2011-12-01' AND '2011-12-07';
```

Assuming mytable to be the table name, created_at to be the date field and amount to be the amount field.

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: Thanks but my table does not contain created_at field since I am working on simple PHP not on any PHP framework. then how will I compare?

Comment: You need to have a date field in the database table, otherwise you can't check on which date that payment record was saved.

Comment: Yes I had a payment_date field in my table and this worked for me. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT amount FROM mytable 
      WHERE 
     created_at >= '2011-12-01' 
       AND 
   created_at <= '2011-12-07';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the sum of the salary between two dates you can do somethig like:

```
SELECT sum(salary) as total FROM table_name 
WHERE job_date BETWEEN 'dd-mm-yyyy' AND 'dd-mm-yyyy';
```